# How do I access a shared volume from terminal?

Tags: mount, shared-folders, plex

I am attempting to use a shared hard disk(Ubuntu 17.04/Windows 10) with a Plex media server, running as a service on the Ubuntu distribution.

However, it accesses the linux file system, and I cannot seem to find the shared drive there.

If I open "Files" on Ubuntu, I have a "967GB Volume" on the left. How would I access it from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition, that is shown as "967GB Volume" on the left can also be seen with the command

```
df
```

or if you wish

```
df -h
```

You can use the `cd` command to change the current directory of a terminal window to the mountpoint, where the partition is mounted.

For example

```
cd /media/cbll/long-uuid-string
ls -l
```

Please ask if you want more details.

Comment: You are right, if mounted, I can see it. Somehow, the /media/ directory is empty if I look from within the Plex interface. Sadly :-(

Comment: That means it is not mounted.it could be dirty if it is a windows filesystem. Linux refuses to mount a dirty filesystem.

Comment: Can you mount and see the partition in your drive via a terminal window, or do you need more help? (I don't know the Plex media interface, but maybe someone who knows will see your question and can help you with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Any external media which is automaticall mounted will be accecible under `/media`.

To get to this on the terminal, simply `cd /media/$USER/`.

To find the path of any folder which you have open in the default file manager, Nautilus, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>:

[image]

Or you can simply drag any file to a terminal to get the full file path:

[image]